# xenforo template hook a button in front of breadcrumb

Tags: xenforo

how can I add/create a call to action button in xenforo template in front of breadcrumb, like we open a category or forum, and you found a create thread button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
<xen:topctrl>
    <a href="{link}" class="callToAction"><span>Whatever</span></a>
</xen:topctrl>
```

Comment: Thanks, you are life saver :D